# Fitting data with weights in a Log-Log scale

Tags: plotting, fitting

I need help.
I have the following dataset:

```
data = {{Around[0.1, {0.09, 0.17}], Around[4.7, {6.4, 6.8}]}, {Around[    0.0143, {0.0077, 0.0077}], Around[7.2, {4.5, 4.5}]}, {Around[    0.1616, {0.0032, 0.0041}], Around[72., {24., 33.}]}}
```

Each point in the dataset has error bars in both X and Y.

How can I make fit this dataset into a Log-Log scale?

Thank you

Comment: The code you have included has extra brackets and doesn't evaluate. Please fix it.

Comment: ```data = {{Around[0.1, {0.09, 0.17}], Around[4.7, {6.4, 6.8}]}, {Around[
   0.0143, {0.0077, 0.0077}], Around[7.2, {4.5, 4.5}]}, {Around[
   0.1616, {0.0032, 0.0041}], Around[72., {24., 33.}]}}```